# PHP: Does using traits a lot impact performance?

Tags: php, performance, traits

I am fond of using traits to keep code clean and not having classes with 2000 lines. However, I wonder if this affects performance negatively? Did anyone test this with real classes?

Regarding some demo code below, is class WithTraits slower than SomeClass?

Best regards
Philipp

```
class SomeClass {

    public function function1() {
        //...    
    }


    public function function2() {
        //...    
    }


    public function function3() {
        //...    
    }
}



trait Function1 {
    
    public function function1() {
        //...    
    }
}

trait Function2 {
    
    public function function2() {
        //...    
    }
}

trait Function3 {
    
    public function function3() {
        //...    
    }
}

class WithTraits {
    
    use Function1;
    use Function2;
    use Function3;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Traits work by copying and pasting the trait into all classes that use it, so there likely is *some* performance impact. However, that isn't a good reason not to use them.

First of all, if you're using the opcode cache (and you should), then the trait gets copied when your PHP is compiled to bytecode, so after that initial compilation step you shouldn't see any significant difference in performance.

Second, this is a good example of a micro-optimization. In most web apps, there are always going to be more significant performance issues, such as:

- Slow, inefficient queries
- N+1 queries
- Repeated requests for data or pages that could have been cached
- Unnecessarily waiting for actions to complete

These can be resolved through means such as refactoring queries, adding indexes, using an ORM's eager loading, caching data or responses, and moving functionality to a message queue where the user doesn't technically need to wait for it.

Compared to these issues, any overhead from pulling in a trait is going to be negligible, and certainly not worth losing the benefits of more readable code and reduced code duplication that you'd get from moving the code to traits. It's certainly not worth worrying about.